# How to write an error handling decorator in typescript

Tags: typescript

One of controller's methods looks as follows:

```
@httpGet('')
public async getProducts(@queryParam() queryBody: object): Promise<Products[]> {
    return this.productService.getProducts(queryBody);
}
```

I'd like to have a decorator, let's say `@Catch()` (if called like this then it should be a decorator factory) that could be used on that method and whose responsibility would be to catch errors/exceptions coming from the service method. I just want to decouple error-handling logic from the logic in the controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a function which will be the decorator `catchError` and in the function change existing function with a wrapped function. You can access existing `bar` function via `descriptor.value`.

There is an issue that return types can change from `catchError` function and will be invisible in typescript.

```
class Foo {
    @catchError
    public bar(message: string): string {
        if(message === "x") {
            throw new Error("x not valid");
        }

        return message;
    }
}

function catchError(target: any,propertyName: any,descriptor: any) {
    const method = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any) {
        try {
            return method.apply(target, args);
        } catch(error) {
            throw new Error(`Special error message: ${error.message}`);
        }
    };
}

const foo = new Foo();
const result = foo.bar("x");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I had to make the descriptor value an `async` function as well and also gotta bind `this` otherwise it complains of not being able to call `getProducts` of `undefined`. That done, it works like a charm.

Comment: @Albert Could you tell me where you bound `this`?